# When does my Magikarp catch fire?

Tags: magikarp-jump

Occassionally after a training session I will notice the message will change from "Time to head home" to "Magikarp is on fire and will swim all the way home".

I know this is a random encounter, but is this encounter tied to the performance you get from doing any sort of training? Does it matter if the performance is good, great, or excellent?

Comment: I think you answered your own question with that it's a random encounter, personally I've seen it happened on any kind of training and any kind of result

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.   A random event doesn't have to be uniformly distributed, it could be random with different chances depending on various factors.  If someone were to do a study on this, it would be very interesting in my opinion.

Comment: Misleading title. Thought Magikarp could literally catch on fire. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as has been disclosed, this is an entirely random event.  There is no clear tie to any particular performance.

Comment: Considering I've gotten slacker magikarp after an amazing performance, I'm pretty sure you're right, and it's totally random.